# Sass Nested Properties

Tags: css, sass

I am learning SASS using W3School tutorial. I am using VS Code and having issue on the following code in scss file.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? There are 3 properties for `font` which you can specify in the same line but like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)

Comment: You only break up selectors this way. Individual property names, like `font-family`, can not be broken up.

Comment: since I am learning I believe tutorial knew what needs to be taught :)

Sass Nested Properties:

Many CSS properties have the same prefix, like font-family, font-size and font-weight or text-align, text-transform and text-overflow.

With Sass you can write them as nested properties:

font: {
  family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  size: 18px;
  weight: bold;
}

Comment: here is the link 
https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_nesting.php

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured that out. It seems tutorial is missing something or they assume learner will know by experience :)

Following scss code should be under a class to work perfectly. I tried and it works.

for example:

writing in mystyle.cscc

```
.content{
  font: {
    family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    size: 18px;
    weight: bold;
  }
}
```

The Sass transpiler will convert the above to normal CSS:

```
.content {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```